# Retain Map Object: Adding multiple maps to a single page in multiple Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add multiple maps on a single page using Jquery dialog and google Maps API V3

Here is my jquery Code:

```
function liveTrack_setMap(accountID, deviceID, displayNameOfVehicle) {
    var divtoBeAdded = '<div class="lt_outerDivClass" id="lt_dialog' + deviceID + '" title="Live Track: ' + displayNameOfVehicle + '" > <input type="hidden" /><div class="lt_map" style="height:200px;width;200px;" id="lt_map' + deviceID + '"></div></div>';
    if ($('#lt_dialog' + deviceID).length == 0) {
        $('body').append(divtoBeAdded);
        alert('new Div Added');
    }
    if ($('#lt_dialog' + deviceID).length != 0) {
        $('#lt_dialog' + deviceID).dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: false,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: true,
            close: function() {
                $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
            }
        });
    }
    if ($('#lt_map' + deviceID).length != 0) {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("lt_map" + deviceID),
            mapOptions);
    }
}
```

After applying the map to the div I'll be using it to update the location of vehicle on the map evry 10 seconds. But the problem is that,

1) The number of divs are not fixed

2) The map object cannot be a global variable as their can be n number of map objects.

3) The map object cannot be accessed by its div ID.

How should I go about it? Any Ideas? Please help.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you save it in a object like this

Declare a global variable:

```
var map_object = {}
```

then at the Time of setting up the map:

```
var index=1;
map_object["map" + index]=new google.maps.......
```

Comment: Thank you.!! Exactly What I wanted.!